# Passing a variable through multiple functions, not getting desired result

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I had this working before I split it into functions. I'm sure it's just a & or * I'm missing somewhere, but I can't seem to figure it out. User enters a number, then they choose F on the menu to have it print 0-number. I'm getting garbage in the display() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char menu();
int read_int(int number);
void display(int number);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
int number = 0;     
char choice = 'O';
while (choice != 'X'){


    choice = menu();    

    if (choice != 'N' && choice != 'F' && choice != 'X'){
        printf("Invalid Input. Enter N, F, or X\n");
    }

    else if (choice == 'N'){
        number = read_int(number);

    }

    else if (choice == 'F'){        
        display(number);            
    }




}

}


char menu ()
{
char i;
printf("\nEnter N to enter an integer from 0 to 20\nEnter F to display the first N+1 numbers (beginning with zero) on the console \nEnter X to quit the program \n");

printf("Your Choice: ");
scanf("%s",  &i);
return i;
}   

int read_int(number)
{
//int number = 0;
printf("\nEnter an integer 0-20: ");
scanf("%d", &number);
if (number >=0 && number <=20)
    return number;
else{
    printf("Enter a valid number between 0 and 20");    
    read_int(number);
}
}

void display(answer)
{
int count = 0;
printf("\nNumber equals: ");
printf("%d", answer);   
//while (count <= number){
//  printf("%d",count);
//  printf(" , ");
//  count++;
//}
}
```

It appears to be working with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char menu();
int read_int(int number);
void display(int answer);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int number = 0;     
    char choice = 'O';
    while (choice != 'X'){


    choice = menu();    

    if (choice != 'N' && choice != 'F' && choice != 'X'){
        printf("Invalid Input. Enter N, F, or X\n");
    }

    else if (choice == 'N'){
        number = read_int(number);
        printf("\nNumber equals: ");
        printf("%d", number);   

    }

    else if (choice == 'F'){
        //printf("\nNumber equals: ");
        //printf("%d", number);         
        display(number);            
    }




}

}


char menu ()
{
    char i; 
    printf("\nEnter N to enter an integer from 0 to 20\nEnter F to display the first N+1 numbers (beginning with zero) on the console \nEnter X to quit the program \n");

    printf("Your Choice: ");
    scanf("%s",  &i);
    return i;
}   

int read_int(int number)
{
number = 0;
    printf("\nEnter an integer 0-20: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (number >=0 && number <=20)
        return number;
    else{
        printf("Enter a valid number between 0 and 20");    
        return read_int(number);
    }
}

void display(int answer)
{
int count = 0;
//printf("\nNumber equals: ");
//printf("%d", answer); 
//int toprint = answer;
while (count <= answer){            
    printf("%d",count);
    printf(" , ");
    count=count+1;
}
}
```

Now to convert it to assembly! Oh boy!

Comment: Your `read_int` doesn't return the result of the recursive call, so the program is undefined. (Its parameter is also pointless.)

Comment: You could  do this in your function `read_int`   `return read_int(number);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char menu (void){
    char i[2];
    printf("\nEnter N to enter an integer from 0 to 20\nEnter F to display the first N+1 numbers (beginning with zero) on the console \nEnter X to quit the program \n");
    printf("Your Choice: ");
    scanf("%1s", i);
    return *i;
}   

int read_int(int number)//add int
{
    printf("\nEnter an integer 0-20: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (number >=0 && number <=20)
        return number;
    else{
        printf("Enter a valid number between 0 and 20");    
        return read_int(number);//add return
    }
}

void display(int answer)//add int
{
    int count = 0;
    printf("\nNumber equals: ");
    printf("%d\n", answer);
}
```

Comment: I've got it set up similar to this, but I still get garbage when calling display(int answer)

Comment: Enter N to enter an integer from 0 to 20<br/>Enter F to display the first N+1 numbers (beginning with zero) on the console 
Enter X to quit the program 
Your Choice: N

Enter an integer 0-20: 5

Number equals: 5
Enter N to enter an integer from 0 to 20
Enter F to display the first N+1 numbers (beginning with zero) on the console 
Enter X to quit the program 
Your Choice: F

Number equals: 00 ,

Comment: Can't figure out the formatting here. Feel retarded. It prints 00 , when the function is called.

Comment: Using Nasm and gcc. Running the same program (not compiling at all, just running ./a.out again, provides totally different results the second /third time. This time I got 50,1,2,3,4,5, so it worked!

Comment: `while (count <= number){` --> `while (count <= answer){` or `void display(int answer)` --> `void display(int number)`

Answer (score 2):

Your scanf() call is wrong:

```
 scanf("%s",  &i);
```

You are reading only one char. It should be:

```
 scanf(" %c",  &i);
```

The leading space (or anywhite space character) character I added will ensure any whitespace chracter left in the input stream will be discarded.

Answer (score 2):

`read_int` doesn't return anything (which means it can return anything) when it makes a recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

Your program behaviour is undefined on the control path that calls `read_int` from itself. You need to *return* that value:

`return read_int(number);`

I'm surprised your compiler didn't warn you about this. Do you have warnings switched off?

(I'd also consider recoding this to remove the recursion; you could overflow your call stack - which is surprisingly small on some platforms - if you have a particularly pernicious user.)